# Write the content of a text file line by line with Svelte

Tags: svelte

i wrote this code in svelte that open a txt file, and write it in a html paragraph. This is the code:

```
<input type='file' multiple bind:files'>

{#if files}
    <h2>Files selected: </h2>
{#each Array.from(files) as file}
<p> IThe imported file is: {file.name}</p>
{#await file.text() then text}
<p>{text}</p>
{/await}
{/each}
{/if}
```

and the example file is like this:

```
beans
spam
donut
```

but it gives me this:

```
beans spam donut
```

how can I create a new line (paragraph or `<br>`) for each line in the text?

Comment: Why not use CSS `white-space: pre-wrap;`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this? Simply split on the newline and create a new p tag.

```
<script>
    let files;
</script>

<input type='file' multiple bind:files />

{#if files}
    <h2>Files selected: </h2>
{#each Array.from(files) as file}
<p> IThe imported file is: {file.name}</p>
{#await file.text() then text}
{#each text.split('\n') as line }
<p>{line}</p>
{/each}
{/await}
{/each}
{/if}
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! I'm just learning svelte and yeah, i think i will study more

Comment: Same here. I am just getting to grips with it, but I am already loving it when compared to React Vue or Angular it seems to be way simpler and faster. BTW I recommend you checkout sveltekit (replacement for Sapper) as it comes with a nice template for larger projects.